# Why doesn't dereferencing the string::iterator raise an error at .end() after compiling from the console?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, iterator

Windows 7 64 SP1,
Boost 1.42,
MS VS 2010 Ultimate,
C++

This stripped down code compiles and runs fine within the "Visual Studio x64 Command Prompt (2010)" using these switches:

`cl /EHsc /W4 /nologo`

```
#include <string>

using namespace std;        // I know not to use.

int main() {

  string sentence = "abc";
  string word_found = "";
  string::const_iterator it = sentence.begin();

  while ( *it != ' ' && it != sentence.end() )  
    word_found += *it++;                        
}
```

However, after compiling within the VS IDE, when run, it crashes with the error:

```
Expression: string iterator not dereferencable
```

The problem is apparently with the `*it` in `( *it != ' ' && it != sentence.end() )`. I just need to short-circuit the expression so the now-right-hand expression,  the `*it != ' '`, doesn't evaluate:

```
while ( it != sentence.end() && *it != ' '  )
```

Then it runs well.

But why does it run flawlessly after compiling the original code from the command prompt? There is no other unusual behavior in the much larger program this subset is derived from. What doesn't the string::iterator cause the same problem?

FWIW, these are the default MS VS command line options: `/ZI /nologo /W3 /WX- /Od /Oy- /D "WIN32" /D "_DEBUG" /D "_CONSOLE" /D "_UNICODE" /D "UNICODE" /Gm /EHsc /RTC1 /GS /fp:precise /Zc:wchar_t /Zc:forScope /Fp"Debug\test short.pch" /Fa"Debug\" /Fo"Debug\" /Fd"Debug\vc100.pdb" /Gd /analyze- /errorReport:queue`

**Why do the command-line compiler and the IDE compiler produce different executables?  Is there a switch I can add to the command prompt compiler that would make the executable behave in the same manner as when compiling from the VS IDE**

Comment: The answer to "But why does it run flawlessly after compiling the original code from the command prompt?" is "Because undefined behaviour is not defined".

Comment: @R.MartinhoFernandes I think he understand that, and is asking "Why do the command-line compiler and the IDE compiler produce different executables?"

Comment: @Therefore, have you tried building from the command-line with **all** of the same switches you used in the IDE?

Comment: I did but without success. I get your point, though, I need to take the time to understand each switch individually and test each one out. A healthy exercise indeed. :)

Comment: If you play with the GUI settings, it'll tell you what most of them are.  Playing with wchar_t settings will show `/Zc:wchar_t` somewhere in the window.

Comment: Where did you find that set of command line options?  In a newly created Empty Project, the Debug configuration includes `/MDd`.  The Project Property Pages should also show this in the C/C++ -> Command Line page, which lists (most of) the options passed to the compiler.

Comment: @James McNellis I cut and pasted from the C/C++->Command Line property page. And I did start with an empty project.

Comment: @James McNellis. But in the C/C++->Code Generation property page the RunTime Library is set to /MDd.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Those runtime checks are only enabled by default in *debug* builds.  You either need to

- build with one of the debug runtimes by compiling with [the `/MDd` or `/MTd` option](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2kzt1wy3.aspx), or
- enable checked iterators by changing the [`_ITERATOR_DEBUG_LEVEL`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh697468.aspx) to `1` (`/D_ITERATOR_DEBUG_LEVEL=1`).

Comment: I see! That was the difference. Thanks. I should have guessed. :)